# wxPython window randomly freezes on RPi and acts weird afterwards

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, wxpython

*This Problem occurs on the RPi (3B+, Raspbian Buster) only. I run the program on my Mac without any problems.*

**Short description of my program:**

After entering the mainloop, the program enters a second thread with another loop (call it requestloop) when the designated button is pressed. The requestloop can be left by pressing the button again. This requestloop requests a xml table via url every 10 seconds which is then parsed with ElementTree, sorted and displayed in a wx.grid.Grid. I use grid.ForceRefresh to make sure the grid is updated.

I hope the following snippet helps to understand the above:

```
    def on_btnrun(self, event):
        global run
        if self.btnrun.Label == "Start":
            run = True
            thrupt = threading.Thread(target=self.thrupdate)
            thrupt.start()
            self.btnrun.SetLabel("Ende")

        elif self.btnrun.Label == "Ende":
            run = False
            self.btnrun.SetLabel("Start")


     def thrupdate(self):
         while run is True:
            reset()
            self.grid.ClearGrid()
            update(self.grid)
            self.grid.ForceRefresh()
            time.sleep(10)
```

**Problem:**

Now as mentioned in the title the whole wx Window freezes after passing the requestloop between roughly 5 and 20 times. This happens completely randomly, I could not find any regularities. The program keeps running though, for it still prints the output in the terminal every cycle (I added this function for testing).
When I now open another window (eg. menu dropwdown) which lays over the wx Window it will be copied onto the wx Window and stay there after I closed it.

Here are some Images to better understand what I mean (ignore all other widgets that I didn't mention, they are just nonfunctional placeholders).

[Image of the wx Window before it freezes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzzSu.png)

[Image of the wx Window after it freezes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryOPU.png)

[Image of the wx Window after opening and closing the dropdown menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oan4A.png)

**Extra-Info**: while building wxPython on the RPi I got some warnings and everytime I run the program I get the following one (it says the actual time instead of time):

`(program.py:1666): Gtk-Critical **: time: gtk_distribute_natural_allocation: assertion ‚extra_space >= 0‘ failed`

**Question:**

I have no idea why any of this happens. Is wxPython not stable on Raspbian? Or did the build partly fail? Or is the RPi not having enough rendering capacity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by using wx.CallAfter in the details of the update() method.